# Remove the Proceed to Checkout button from the Shopping Cart page in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, paypal-express

is there an easy way to remove the "Proceed to Checkout" button from the shopping cart page?  Instead I would like the "Check out with PayPal" to be the only option.  I suppose I would need the word "OR" to also be hidden.